# get unique values from 1 column and sum up 2 next columns

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
A 500 100 ABC
B 200 100 BBB
B 200 100 ACC
D 150 235 CDD
A 500 100 RER
C 210 653 DDD
C 210 653 DWR
D 150 653 DDW
D 150 653 DER
```

What I try to accomplish is to filter out the first for unique names 
and get a total of all of the value behind it (sum of column 2 and 3) eg:

```
A 1000 200
B 400 200
```

I got it sort of working for the first 2 with the following awk line:

```
awk '{a[$1]+=$2} END {for(i in a) print i,a[i] }' file
```

That results in:

```
A 1000
B 400
```

I'm stuck on adding the 3th column in the mix. 
Does anyone have the tip for adding column 3?

Comment: hint: `b[$1] += $3`

Comment: ha... I actually tried that, but without ;   Works now.. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this tested version a try:

```
awk '{ colone[$1]+=$2; coltwo[$1]+=$3; } END { for (i in colone) { print i " " colone[i] " " coltwo[i]; }}' file
```

It is using associative arrays, see the famous tutorial [Awk - A Tutorial and Introduction - by Bruce Barnett](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-22)

The test is below:

```
awk '{ colone[$1]+=$2; coltwo[$1]+=$3; } END { for (i in colone) { print i " " colone[i] " " coltwo[i]; }}' file
A 1000 200 
B 400 200
C 420 1306
D 450 1541
```